# Android studio code insight not showing everything

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Android Studio shows code suggestions, but not all available codes are in the suggestion.
For example, `layout_alignParentLeft` will not be suggested, however, the documentation still shows it is a valid code.

Is there a setting that enables Android Studio to show all available codes?
[image: Code suggestion]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the parent of yourview is a `ConstraintLayout`which doesn't have the attribute `layout_alignParentLeft`.

Try with a RelativeLayout instead and then you will see `layout_alignParentLeft` into the suggestions.